# How to custom match large pandas dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two large `pandas` DataFrame `df1` (sorted by `paper`):

```
reference                     paper
10.1103/PhysRevB.1.3614       10.1103/PhysRev.91.174           (*)
10.1103/PhysRev.92.1367       10.1103/PhysRev.91.174
10.1103/RevModPhys.62.251     10.1103/PhysRev.91.174
10.1103/PhysRevA.10.1494      10.1103/PhysRev.91.174
10.1103/PhysRevD.74.085005    10.1103/PhysRev.91.174
10.1103/PhysRevB.7.3541       10.1103/PhysRev.113.115
10.1103/PhysRevB.1.2088       10.1103/PhysRev.113.115
10.1103/PhysRevB.1.3614       10.1103/PhysRev.113.115          (**)
10.1103/RevModPhys.57.1055    10.1103/PhysRevLett.10.486
10.1103/PhysRevB.76.064524    10.1103/PhysRevLett.10.486
...
```

and `df2` (custom sorted):

```
pair1                         pair2
10.1103/PhysRevA.30.336       10.1103/PhysRevA.34.1617
10.1103/PhysRevA.30.336       10.1103/PhysRevA.34.4472
10.1103/PhysRevA.30.336       10.1103/PhysRevA.41.784
10.1103/PhysRevA.34.4472      10.1103/PhysRevA.41.784   
10.1103/PhysRevA.36.4950      10.1103/PhysRevA.41.784   
10.1103/PhysRevA.38.3688      10.1103/PhysRevA.41.784   
10.1103/PhysRevA.41.3081      10.1103/PhysRevA.41.784   
10.1103/PhysRevA.30.336       10.1103/PhysRevA.45.5469  
10.1103/PhysRevA.34.4472      10.1103/PhysRevA.45.5469  
10.1103/PhysRev.91.174        10.1103/PhysRev.113.115          (#)
...
```

I want to match the two DataFrames into a single DataFrame `df` that looks like:

```
reference                     pair1                     pair2
10.1103/PhysRevB.1.3614       10.1103/PhysRev.91.174    10.1103/PhysRev.113.115   (*)(**)(#)
...
```

(I marked the indicators `(*)` `(**)` `(#)` for a more helpful understanding)

The conditions of the matching are:

1. `reference` and `pair1` from `df` must correspond to `reference` and `paper` in `df1`. (*)
2. `reference` and `pair2` from `df` must correspond to `reference` and `paper` in `df1`. (**)
3. `pair1` and `pair2` from `df` must correspond to `pair1` and `pair2` in `df2`. (#)

Hence, `reference` must cite **both** `pair1` **and** `pair2` as `paper` in `df1` to be able to be registered as a data point in `df`.

---

I tried merging `df1` and `df2` twice:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='paper', right_on='pair1', how='inner')
df = df.merge(df2, left_on='paper', right_on='pair2', how='inner')
df = df.drop(['paper'], axis=1)
```

but failed as this produces incorrect data points, e.g. `reference` citing only one of the `pair1` or `pair2` in `df1` but still being registered in `df`. (Not to mention crashing the RAM due to excessive runtime)

I also have tried making the DataFrames into lists and match the queries:

```
list1 = df1.values.tolist()
list2 = df2.values.tolist()

citlist = []
p1list = []
p2list = []

sublist = []
matches = []
citname = '10.1103/PhysRevB.1.3614'

for i in list1:
    # First data point
    if i[0] == citname:
        sublist.append(i[1])
    # For all data points
    if i[0] != citname:
        # Find matches
        for j in list2:
            if j[0] in sublist and j[1] in sublist:
                matches.append(j)
        for h in matches:
            citlist.append(citname)
            p1list.append(h[0])
            p2list.append(h[1])
        sublist = []
        matches = []
        citname = i[0]
        sublist.append(i[1])
    # Last data point
    if citname == '10.1103/PhysRevE.80.061802':
        for j in list2:
            if j[0] in sublist and j[1] in sublist:
                matches.append(j)
        for h in matches:
            citlist.append(citname)
            p1list.append(h[0])
            p2list.append(h[1])
```

But then I run into a problem of this not producing any matched queries between `df1` and `df2` somehow. (This approach also takes 21 hours to run)

Any insights on this custom matching?

Comment: ur question description is a bit confusing. what is df? r u referring to df1?df2?

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, `df` would be the final matched dataset that I want to acquire.

Comment: yeah. i'm referring to ur conditions for matching, u mentioned df, instead of df1 or df2. i assume for the conditions, it should be only df1 and df2? kindly check

Comment: @sammywemmy ah I see. They aren't incorrectly described, but indeed confusingly written. To rephrase, each datapoint in `df` (`reference`, `pair1`, and `pair2`) has to be also in `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: @sammywemmy `reference` and `pair1` have to be in `df1` (as `reference` and `paper`), `reference` and `pair2` have to be in `df1` (as `reference` and `paper`), and 
`pair1` and `pair2` have to be in `df2` (as `pair1` and `pair2`). Only when every condition is satisfied, the data are "matched" and can be registered in the final dataset `df`.

Comment: if you could provide df.columns for each DF maybe it would be less confusing.

Comment: Hi @CarlosPCeballos, I thought I provided the columns for `df1`, `df2`, and `df`. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: so `df1.columns = [reference, paper, pair1, pair2]` and `df2.columns = [reference, pair1, pair2]`. Is that correct?

Comment: @CarlosPCeballos `df1.columns = [reference, paper]`, `df2.columns = [pair1, pair2]`. The matched dataset I want to acquire, `df`, has: `df.columns = [reference, pair1, pair2]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need both DFs, if I understood the example correctly all the data is in DF1:

```
df['paper'] = df.groupby(['reference'])['paper'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x)).drop_duplicates()

df = pd.DataFrame(df['paper'].str.split(',',1).tolist(), columns = ['pair1','pair2'])
```

Comment: I need `df2` because `df2` shows which `paper` from `df1` are actually pairs. I just ran the `unstack` code to check, and it seems like it simply returns the same dataframe.

Comment: @Robin, I changed the solution, it's less elegant, but works with your example data. Let me know if that works

Comment: The unstack required a multi index, I missed that in the example. But check that functionality, it's handy: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Comment: I checked the `unstack` functionality and tried the code, but it seems like for some reason, the first line of code produces `NaN`s. Could it be that it is caused by `drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: Also, I added the indicators in the question to reduce confusion.

Comment: @Robin I changed the answer, give it a try and let me know if it works, it worked for me using your sample data